# Prefix Parsing using Prolog

Tags: parsing, prolog

So I have this grammar:

```
  expr(op(T,B,E)) => [term(T), binop(B), expr(E)].
  expr(T) => [term(T)].

  term(N) => [num(N)].
  term(L) => [lvalue(L)].
  term(pre(O,L)) => [incrop(O), lvalue(L)].
  term(post(L,O)) => [lvalue(L), incrop(O)].
  term(E) => ['(', expr(E), ')'].

  lvalue($(E)) => [$, expr(E)].

  incrop(++) => [++].
  incrop(--) => [--].

  binop(+) => [+].
  binop(-) => [-].

  num(0) => [0].
  num(1) => [1].
  num(2) => [2].
  num(3) => [3].
  num(4) => [4].
  num(5) => [5].
  num(6) => [6].
  num(7) => [7].
  num(8) => [8].
  num(9) => [9].
```

and the goal is to parse the input according to the rules, and separate the remaining suffix. For example,

```
| ?- parse_prefix(expr(E), [$,1,+,2], S).

E = op($(1),+,2)
S = [] ? ;

E = $(op(1,+,2))
S = [] ? ;

E = $(1)
S = [+,2] ? ;

no
```

and

```
| ?- parse_prefix(expr(E), [9], S).

E = 9
S = [] ? ;

no


| ?- parse_prefix(expr(E), [9,+,$,1,+], S).

E = op(9,+,$(1))
S = [+] ? ;

E = 9
S = [+,$,1,+] ? ;
```

I have written the following predicates:

```
%Base Case: No Token, No Suffix
parse_prefix(_,[],[]).

%Direct Matching: ex) parse_prefix(num(9),[9],S)
parse_prefix(NT,[Head|Tail],S):-
    NT =>[Head],
    write('two '),
    parse_prefix(expr(E),Tail,S).
%General Matching: ex) parse_prefix(expr(E),_,S)
parse_prefix(NT,[Head|Tail],S):-
    NT => [Head1|Tail1],
    %write(Head1),
    %write('one\n'),
    parse_prefix(Head1,[Head|Tail],S).
```

and I'm having a lot of confusion with recursion and backtracking..

I will permanently love anyone who can help me this one.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please describe what the output should look like.

Comment: I guess what he describes by "the goal is to parse the input according to the rules, and separate the remaining suffix." is the usual behaviour of the two extra arguments in DCG. And since he doesn't use a cut or somesuch in the grammar rules it is probably valid that [$,1,+,2] gets two complete parses with an empty suffix, i.e. op($(1),+,2) and $(op(1,+,2)), as he exemplarly requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already close to a solution. It is good to define your own operator =>/2 to represent your own gammar rules and not get into conflict with -->/2. But I am having problems with the representation of grammar rule bodies. I don't see that you distinguish terminals and non-terminals in the grammar rule bodies.

One suggestion would be to vote for (A1,...,An) to represent a conjunction in the body, instead of [A1,..,An]. And then use [T] for terminals and NT for non-terminals. So the following rule,

```
term(E) => ['(', expr(E), ')'].
```

would then read:

```
term(E) => ['('], expr(E), [')'].
```

You can then adapt your rules and define a parse_prefix/3 as follows. I show you the terminal and the conjunction and the non-terminal case:

```
parse_prefix([T],I,O) :- !, I=[T|O].
parse_prefix((A,B),I,O) :- !, parse_prefix(A,I,H), parse_prefix(B,H,O).
parse_prefix(NT,I,O) :- (NT => Body), parse_prefix(Body,I,O).
```

You can add additional cases for the empty production ([]) and auxiliary conditions ({}), or make it more flexible to be able to work with terminal lists ([T1,..,Tn]). Also further control constructs are possible, but when you try to do a cut (!) things get a little bit nasty when following the meta-interpreter approach.

Instead of writing a meta-interpreter parse_prefix/3 you could also cook your own term rewriting to finally arrive at a method that would convert the given gammar rules first into ordinary Prolog and then execute them from there. You find a simple recipe here:

http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/blog/en/docs/int/jan/098_2011/097_dcg_expansion/package.html

Bye